# Web page elements from base.html and extended page on different rows instead of same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I'm new to HTML/Jinja/CSS and have been experimenting with making a web page that pulls from a sqlite3 database. Currently, I'm having issue with formatting.

I've imported bootstrap to help with table formatting and general appearances.

I have a base.html file and a page.html file. The base.html file looks like this:

```
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="centered-wrapper">Nexus Gamification</div>
<div>Points
<li><a href="/teams">Team Points</a></li>
<li><a href="/individual">Individual Points</a></li>
    <ul>
       <a href="/indivConnect">Connect</a>
       <a href="/indivDevelop">Develop</a>
       <a href="/indivLead">Lead</a>
       <a href="/indivLearn">Learn</a>
    <ul>
</div>
<li><a href="/events">Past Events</a></li>
<hr>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

afterwards my page.html looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <table class="table table-striped" align="center">
     ... 
     </table>
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Instead of the table appearing to the direct right of the links in the page, it appears below and to the right of the links. I want the links to be in a sidebar type deal and instead it's as if the two elements are on a different row. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it because I have a body in the base.html and a body in the 'extended' page?

Comment: i posted an answer. but 1 question becouse i will need to edit my answer otherwise do you want to allign the links left and the block contend right next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i understand correctly. you `{% block %}` displays under the links.

if that is correct. delete the `<hr>` that is skipping a line. so all the content under the `<hr>` tag is underneath it AND youre using 2 body's. it should just be one body.

1. Delete the `<hr>`
2. in **THE BLOCK** you should delete the `<body>` tag
3. And add a  `</body>` right underneath the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`.

split.

```
<body>
    <div class="centered-wrapper">Nexus Gamification</div>
<div>Points
<li><a href="/teams">Team Points</a></li>
<li><a href="/individual">Individual Points</a></li>
<ul>
   <a href="/indivConnect">Connect</a>
   <a href="/indivDevelop">Develop</a>
   <a href="/indivLead">Lead</a>
   <a href="/indivLearn">Learn</a>
<ul>
</div>
<li><a href="/events">Past Events</a></li>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
```

---

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <table class="table table-striped" align="center">
       ... 
      </table>
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```